# creating a new data frame using differences between two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is a subset of a data frame:

```
index  id   drug   sentences     SS1   SS2
1      2    lex     very bad      0     1
2      3    gym     very nice     1     1
3      7    effex   hard          1     0 
4      8    cymba   poor          1     1
```

I would like to find rows that SS1 and SS2 are different and then create a new data frame based on that. The output should be like that:

```
index  id   drug   sentences     SS1   SS2
1      2    lex     very bad      0     1
3      7    effex   hard          1     0
```

This is my code:

```
df [['index','id', 'drug', 'sentences', 'SS1', 'SS2' ]] = np.where(df.SS1 != df.SS2)
```

But it has the following error: `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray`

Any suggestion?

Comment: @open-source already gave you a working alternative, but just for reference, you got a `ValueError` because `np.where(df.SS1 != df.SS2)` returns an index for which your evaluation holds, not a `DataFrame`.

Comment: @peterfields thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way may be following:

```
df_new = df[df.SS1 != df.SS2]
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
    index  id   drug sentences  SS1  SS2
0      1   2    lex  very bad    0    1
2      3   7  effex      hard    1    0
```

Using `where`:

```
df_new = df.where(df.SS1 != df.SS2).dropna()
print(df_new)
```